# Run some code when app is killed

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to develop a mobile application which interact with ibeacons !

I'm developing this application for iPhone and android ! But i have problem !When i was developing iphone app, everything works,
i receive my notification even if my app is killed !

But on android i don't know how can i develop that !
If my application is on background, it works but if i kill my app, nothing happen !

Do you have an idea to run my code even if app is killed?

Thank by advance!

Comment: How to execute some code after receiving the push notification. Like replying back to the server with some data after receiving the push notification on the killed ios app via FCM or APNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want run some code in background even if your application is killed you should use [services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html). From google documentation:

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background, and it does not provide a user interface. Another application component can start a service, and it continues to run in the background even if the user switches to another application. Additionally, a component can bind to a service to interact with it and even perform interprocess communication (IPC). For example, a service can handle network transactions, play music, perform file I/O, or interact with a content provider, all from the background.

If your app runs in scheduled times you can use JobScheduler or AlarmManger. JobScheduler and AlarmManager wrok with services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Service. It will still working even if your activity is killed.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: How to execute some code after receiving the push notification. Like replying back to the server with some data after receiving the push notification on the killed ios app via FCM or APNS?